# To show the default value and maintain ordering in dropdown values

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am working on an application that needs to display a set of questions as a drop down(the user needs to answer 3 questions) in the jsp page.

It works fine, but the issue is for each time I display the drop down list(the questions are same), the questions selected by default are different - the actual question I set in the controller. I need to be able to just display the first or "Select" string as the default option.

My jsp:

```
<tr>
    <br />
    <form:label path="qs1">
        <span class="">qs 1</span>
    </form:label>
    <br />
    <form:select path="qs1" multiple="false">
        <form:option value="${obj.qs0}" label="${obj.qs0}" />
        <form:option value="${obj.qs1}" label="${obj.qs1}" />********In this instance this option is shown in the drop down
        <form:option value="${obj.qs2}" label="${obj.qs2}" />
        <form:option value="${obj.qs3}" label="${obj.qs3}" />
    </form:select>
    <br />
</tr>

<tr>
    <br />
    <form:label path="as1">
        <span class="">as 1</span>
    </form:label>
    <br />
    <form:input class=""  path="as1" />
    <br />
</tr>

<tr>
    <br />
    <form:label path="qs2">
        <span class="">qs 2</span>
    </form:label>
    <br />
    <form:select path="qs2" multiple="false">
        <form:option value="${obj.qs0}" label="${obj.qs0}" />
        <form:option value="${obj.qs1}" label="${obj.qs1}" />
        <form:option value="${obj.qs2}" label="${obj.qs2}" />********In this instance this option is shown in the drop down
        <form:option value="${obj.qs3}" label="${obj.qs3}" />
    </form:select>
    <br />
</tr>

<tr>
    <br />
    <form:label path="as2">
        <span class="">as 2</span>
    </form:label>
    <br />
    <form:input class=""  path="as2" />
    <br />
</tr>
```

I even tried selected="selected" for the right ones, but it did not work. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I should have been clear. I did try the option Amit suggested, as of now the obj.qs0 has the value instead of mentioning that in the JSP. I have just added that option along with the questions. The issue is I need to set the questions to the Questions object like below

```
Questions qs = new Questions();
qs.setQs0("----------Select-------------");
qs.setQs1("what is the name");
qs.setQs2("what is the color");
```

and so on.

So in the jsp I am setting the path

```
<form:select path="qs1" multiple="false">
<form:select path="qs2" multiple="false">
```

So those questions(q1, q2, and so on) are selected automatically and I cannot change the selection to always point to the qs0(where I have the default option). I also need to set the paths differently as I need to be able to capture the different questions & answers the users select.

Answer (score 0):

1) To display "Select"  as default, you can add below line :-

```
 <form:select path="qs1" multiple="false">
    **<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />**
    <form:option value="${obj.qs0}" label="${obj.qs0}" />
    <form:option value="${obj.qs1}" label="${obj.qs1}" />
    <form:option value="${obj.qs2}" label="${obj.qs2}" />
    <form:option value="${obj.qs3}" label="${obj.qs3}" />
</form:select>
```

2) Use the LinkedHashMap or LinkedList to store the drop-down values in order to maintain ordering.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have updated my post with additional comments.

Comment: I still have this issue. Any thing else that I can try? Thanks.